# Why is PECL installing a beta package?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. If I type

```
# pecl install apc
```

it tries to install 3.1.13 which [is beta](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) rather than 3.1.9.

```
$ pear config-get preferred_state
stable
```

Looking inside the two archives there's package.xml that has the following:

3.1.9:

```
<version>
 <release>3.1.9</release>
 <api>3.1.0</api>
</version>
<stability>
 <release>stable</release>
 <api>stable</api>
</stability>
```

3.1.13:

```
<version>
 <release>3.1.13</release>
 <api>3.1.0</api>
</version>
<stability>
 <release>beta</release>
 <api>stable</api>
</stability>
```

I'm inferring from this that 3.1.13 is genuinely considered beta, but I don't know about PECL package internals.
Any idea how I can have PECL install just the latest stable package?

Comment: Are you sure that web page just isn't out of date? Seems odd that the 3.1.13 would be in beta for > 1 year.

Comment: Also 3.1.7 is beta too... I would trust the package state.

Comment: @slm I've added details that might indicate it really is beta, thanks.